# UNIQUE KEY constraint violation to insert duplicate key in object SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This my source table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reseau]
(
    [Trig] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Nom] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Prenom] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [code_delegation] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [CIV] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Fonction] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SEGMENT_C] [bit] NULL,
    [Mail] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    [del_tel_fil] [float] NULL,
    [del_tel_port] [float] NULL,
    [date_creation][datimeoffeset] getdate null, 
    [date_modification][datimeoffeset] getdate null
)
```

This is my destination table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[membre]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [nom] [varchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [prenom] [varchar](40) NULL,
    [telephone_fixe] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [telephone_portable] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [id_adresse] [int] NULL,
    [id_creation] [int] NULL,
    [id_modification] [int] NULL,
    [id_compte] [int] NULL,
    [date_debut] [datetimeoffset](7) NOT NULL,
    [date_fin] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [date_creation] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [date_modification] [datetimeoffset](7) NULL,
    [id_civilite] [int] NULL,
    [id_fonction] [int] NULL,
    [id_segment] [int] NULL,
    [code] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
)
```

This is my query

```
insert into membre (nom, prenom Email, code, date_debut, date_creation, date_modification, id_civ
id_fonction,  segement_c
select nom, prenom, mail as Email, trigs as code, gatedate as date_debut, date_creation, date_modification, civ as id_civ, fonction as id_fonction 

from reseau
```

When I want to insert this data, I get this error:

> Violation of the UNIQUE KEY constraint “unique_email_member”. Cannot insert duplicate key in object "dbo.member". Duplicate key value: ().

Can you help me please?

Thank you

Comment: You also have inconsistency of data types, nullability and max lengths - `[Nom] [nvarchar](max) NULL` goes into `[nom] [varchar](40) NOT NULL` for instance - Solving only the email issue (which can be done quite easilty, actually) is probably not going to be good enough. Other errors might happen, or worst - data might be truncated silently.

Comment: There are multiple errors in the code you're showing us. So you're showing us code that *you yourself have never run* and then asking us about an error message that you have no idea whether this code, once fixed, will demonstrate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unique constraint on the destination table.

The unique constraint forces all records in the table to have a different email address. If anything, you could filter the SELECT statement you used to INSERT rows.

Use a proper WHERE clause to filter any records that may violate the unique constraint, before you insert them into the destination table.

Whats left is a couple of business related questions which can probably not be answered on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have a `UNIQUE` index on the `email` field but you try to insert a row with an `email` that already exists in another row, probably an *empty* email! (if two rows would have an empty email, the value "empty string" for the email would no longer be unique!)

If you don't want the email to be unique, remove the unique constraint/index. If you want to allow empty emails (more than once) while still keeping the non-empty emails unique, then you need to use `NULL` instead of an empty string (and change the column to allow `NULL`).

It seems your source table already allows `NULL` and only your destination table doesn't so maybe that is the issue - if your original table had `NULL`s they would now become an empty string and cause this problem. Then the solution would be to just change the `NOT NULL` to `NULL` for `email` in the destination table.

Comment: i triend to make case when mail = '' then 'non renseigné" when mail is null "non renseigné' else mail end 
the problem is the same

Comment: Yes because then `non renseigné` wouldn't be unique either! Either you keep the `NULL`s as `NULL`s or you remove the requirement for uniqueness. (or you drop rows without emails entirely)

Comment: the unique constraint forces all records in the table to have a different email address. you can filter the SELECT statement you used to INSERT rows to filter any records that may violate the unique constraint before you insert them into the destination table

Comment: I do not have the right to modify the destination table. Can you seggest me a query ?

Comment: Depends on what you want the result to be... What do you want to do with duplicate or empty emails, since your destination table requires them to exist and be unique?

Answer (score -1):

In your insert list there is a comma missing :
insert into membre (nom, **prenom Email**, code...